# Python script doesn't receive arguments from vim's system()

Tags: python, vim, translation

I'm trying to translate text in vim with advise from [Replace visual selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52474689/replace-visual-selection-with-command-output). But when I call `system('ru2uk', getreg('"'))` (args transmited by system's argument) python script doesn't receive args by `txt=' '.join(sys.argv[1:])`. Concatenation works, the code: `system('ru2uk ' . getreg('"'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `:h system()`

> When {input} is given and is a string this string is written to a file and passed as stdin to the command.

So the second argument of `system()` is not "a command-line argument", it's stdin data. And it must be treated properly.